# SELECT statement inside Loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

Our application uses the Rails apartment gem so each microsite has its own schema. Hence we have 50 schemas each with their own user table.

Using SQL(Postgres), how would select users from all 50 schemas without having to loop through each schema?

```
    DO $$
DECLARE
table_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR schema_name IN SELECT schema FROM tenants LOOP
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' ||  schema_name || '.users';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

RESULT

```
subdomain1, 'john smith'
subdomain1, 'mary smith'
subdomain2, 'charles geiger'
subdomain2, 'ann geiger'
subdomain3, 'allison reidy'
```

Comment: So you have 50 different tables with same name, but each one in a different schema?

Comment: That is correct. It's actually 97 schemas as of a minute ago. The website's developers used the gem: https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Comment: @parfait - Unfortunately, I'm only doing a data analytics for an existing project. I wasn't hired to work on the website which was developed by a publicly company.

Comment: If I was tasked with doing analytics on this, I would develop an ETL process to pull from every schema and shove it into a new one that has the same tables, each with an extra column to delineate source schema. Then I'd build by analytics on top of that (could also be moved to another database entirely). Then you run a job to keep it all updated.

Comment: What about create a view with a JOIN with all the tables? I know you dont want create a new model but fail to see what is the problem.

Comment: @Parfait - I asked them about it and their response is the following: "The gem that we used allows some micro-sites to use external databases (not controlled by us) and separate schemas for others. Each of our clients has admin access to their schema so they can edit records as they see fit (ex: can edit their users)".

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza - How would I create a join for all 97 tables? I did it for 10  but then new ones were added. :(

Comment: @JNevill - What are your thoughts on this? https://github.com/cpoms/querrel

Comment: Ok,  First check what are the tables in the db. `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;` then create a DYNAMIC QUERY to `UNION` all the tables.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Yes! That's exactly what I'm asking for if I can figure it out. Instead of SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables, the line I had in the question gives the name of each schema. SELECT subdomain FROM tenants;

Comment: Can you show me a picture of your db to see the different tables?

Comment: There is no way you can do this without a loop. But you can put that loop into a function, then use it like `select * from get_everything('table_name')`

Comment: @JohnCutler That looks pretty cool. Just thinking through what it must do underneath the hood... it has two options: 1) Query every schema independently and then stack the returned recordsets. 2) Query metadata tables, craft a UNION, and then execute the single statement. I'm not sure which direction they went, but both are going to be slow and taxing, which is why extracting, then analyzing is the better option here. There is just no way to make a query reasonable to write AND also performant with this schema. Well.. there is and that's the basis for an MPP, but that's not what you have here.

Comment: @jnevill - It's a table that the Rails app uses when creating a migration. Hence, it's a static list. - https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can generate a query you are looking for:

```
WITH relevant_tables AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(nspname, '.', relname) as table_name,
                 CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', nspname, '.', relname) as table_query
      FROM pg_class c
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE relkind = 'r'
      AND relname = 'users'
)
SELECT string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ') as final_query FROM relevant_tables
```

You can then use a `DO` block to execute it.

`edit considering comments`:

```
WITH relevant_tables AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(nspname, '.', relname) as table_name,
                 CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', nspname, '.', relname) as table_query,
                 nspname as schema
      FROM pg_class c
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE relkind = 'r'
      AND relname = 'users'
)
SELECT string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ') as final_query
FROM relevant_tables a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schema FROM tenants) b ON a.schema = b.schmea
WHERE b.schema IS NOT NULL
```

So all together even with a `DO` block and storing result into table (`schema.table`):

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
    stmt = (
      WITH relevant_tables AS (
    SELECT CONCAT(nspname, '.', relname) as table_name,
           CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', nspname, '.', relname) as table_query,
           nspname as schema
      FROM pg_class c
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     WHERE relkind = 'r'
       AND relname = 'users'
  )
  SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schema.table; CREATE TABLE schema.table AS ', string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ')) as final_query
    FROM relevant_tables a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schema FROM tenants) b ON a.schema = b.schmea
   WHERE b.schema IS NOT NULL
    );
    EXECUTE stmt;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: This doesn't grab the schema names from the table `SELECT schema FROM tenants`.

Comment: check edit: I left-joined your table and took only those schema names which are in your `tenants` object

Comment: How do I add the do block to the code above as that's the most important part? Thank you very much for your help! New schemas are added regularly and removed and it's not feasible for someone to manually edit the SQL query every time.

Comment: In case you want to execute this query and store the results into some table (`schema.table`) then you could just replace `string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ')` by `CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schema.table; CREATE TABLE schema.table AS ', string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL '))`.

Comment: I assume that your latest comment is a joke as it recommends dropping tables. There seems to be some confusion that this question was about getting a list of the schema/table names.

Comment: I edited the answer. Drop+create part is just creating some table which will contain the results of this query. Drop part is not necessary, it could be changed to insert.

Comment: I'm not looking to create a new table.

Comment: So I guess you do not need that DO block at all.

Comment: We still have yet to dynamically get a list of all the users. The code above only generates what we already had done manually though it still doesn't run it.

Comment: To run it in a `DO` block, you have to know what to do with the result. Your idea was only call a query to display it? That is why I added create table part which will store your result into a table.
Once you have created table with most recent results you can easily access its results in your daily job.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [`UNION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) operator, specifically `UNION ALL`.

The basic form is:

```
SELECT a,b,c
  FROM schema1.table
UNION ALL
SELECT a,b,c
  FROM schema2.table
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
  ...
```

Basically, you can put `UNION ALL` between two different `SELECT` statements, and your query will return the results of both `SELECT`s in a single result set.

Note that this only works if both `SELECT` queries return the same set of datatypes. So...

```
SELECT an_int, another_int, a_text
  ...
UNION ALL
SELECT a_text, another_text, a_timestamp
  ...
```

will throw an error.

Since you can put it between `SELECT` statements, you can chain lots of `SELECT` statements in a row. Yes, even 97 of them, if that's what you need.

Because it can be cumbersome, often times people will create a view of the `UNION ALL` query and go against that. In your case, that view would have to be updated for every new schema, so it may not be workable, but it's an option.

Oh, almost forgot. The `ALL` part just means "return all the results from each query". If you just use `UNION` without the `ALL`, the database will go through a de-duplication process. If, for example, you have the same `user` in two different schemas for example, it would only return one of them. `UNION ALL` will return both.

Finally, one bit which can make things down the line a little easier is, if you do create a view, include the source. Something like

```
CREATE VIEW blah AS
  SELECT 'schema1', a,b,c
    FROM schema1.table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'schema2', a,b,c
    FROM schema2.table
  UNION ALL
  ...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: New schemas are added when new tenants are added, you need a dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which even allows you to run it as a query with just printing result:

First, run this command to create a function which will call the query (change `some_schema` to schema you can use to store it and `some_function_name` to a name you want to use). I do not know what the result should look like as I did not see your data but if it will be a table with 2 varchar columns (`subdomain` and `name`) then it will be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_schema.some_function_name()
returns TABLE(subdomain varchar(300), name varchar(300))
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
  BEGIN
    stmt = (
      WITH relevant_tables AS (
        SELECT CONCAT(nspname, '.', relname) as table_name,
        CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', nspname, '.', relname) as table_query,
        nspname as schema
        FROM pg_class c
        LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
        WHERE relkind = 'r'
        AND relname = 'users'
      )
      SELECT string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ') as final_query
      FROM relevant_tables a
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schema FROM tenants) b ON a.schema = b.schmea
      WHERE b.schema IS NOT NULL
    );
    return query EXECUTE stmt;
  end; $BODY$
language plpgsql
;
```

Having this function you can then just run:

```
select * from some_schema.some_function_name()
```

and you should see your results.

Hope this helps.